# Change Chapter/Section styles

Tags: greek, naming

What i would like to achieve is this:

```
Chapter 1. Introduction
Section 1.1 Name of the section 1.1 
Section 1.2 Name of the section 1.2 
...
```

Also i would like to change Chapter and Section "names" into something in Greek. 
All my document is in Greek. For example it will look like:

```
Κεφάλαιο 1. Εισαγωγή
Υποκεφάλαιο 1.1 Δοκιμή 
Υποκεφάλαιο 1.2 Ανάλυση
```

I would like to see something similar in the table of contents as well.

```
Κεφάλαιο 1. Εισαγωγή ............2
Υποκεφάλαιο 1.1 Δοκιμή ..........2
Υποκεφάλαιο 1.2 Ανάλυση .........3
```

Existing code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}}
 \addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\sectionname}{Δοκιμή}} 
\begin{document} 
\chapter{Test chapter} 
\section{Dokimi} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! what you shoe is standard latex features. you only need to use  greek fonts and babel. please show us, what you try so far.

Comment: The problem is not the greek letters. I would like to give a special name to the section as i do with the Chapter. 

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\sectionname}{Δοκιμή}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Dokimi}

\end{document}

Comment: does greek label not translate english names to the greeks one? please move code to your question and extend it to complete small document, which we can test as it is.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting images it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what you are doing and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. It is really difficult to help you without seeing some code.

Comment: @Zarko Done. Andrew Done. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Zarko, the idea is instead of having 1.1 as a section name i will have a title for example Section 1.1 etc. What i mean is that i would like to keep a word i.e. "section" in front of every section number. This word i would like to name it something in Greek.